# gdal2tiles "ERROR 5: Illegal values for buffer size" error for a single zoom level only

Tags: raster, gdal, gdal2tiles

I'm experiencing what seems to be a very particular issue when running gdal2tiles on a virtual raster at zoom levels 10 to 17. The function runs without issue for all zoom levels ***except*** for zoom level 16, where I receive an **"ERROR 5: Illegal values for buffer size"** error.

I'm using gdal2tiles version 2.1.3, and the command I'm using is nothing out of the ordinary:
`gdal2tiles -s EPSG:3857 -z 16 georef\output.vrt tiles`

I've run the function at various levels using a verbose command, and I believe the issue is related to the Native Extent being set to (0,0,0,611) for the first tile, which (I *think*) gives the tile a width of zero. The verbose output for zoom level 16 is shown below:

```
('Options:', <Values at 0x7f77e7661e60: {'profile': 'mercator', 'kml': False, 's_srs': 'EPSG:3857', 'copyright': '', 'resume': False, 'url': '', 'googlekey': 'INSERT_YOUR_KEY_HERE', 'bingkey': 'INSERT_YOUR_KEY_HERE', 'webviewer': 'all', 'zoom': '16', 'quiet': None, 'resampling': 'average', 'tmscompatible': None, 'title': 'output.vrt', 'srcnodata': None, 'verbose': True}>)
('Input:', 'output.vrt')
('Output:', 'tiles')
Cache: 395 MB

('Input file:', '( 91664P x 68298L - 3 bands)')
NODATA: []
('Preprocessed file:', '( 91664P x 68298L - 3 bands)')
('Bounds (output srs):', 0.0, -68298.0, 91664.0, 0.0)
('Bounds (latlong):', (-0.6135196480581518, 0.0), (0.0, 0.823431722035318))
('MinZoomLevel:', 16)
('MaxZoomLevel:', 16, '(', 2.388657133911758, ')')
Generating Base Tiles:

Tiles generated from the max zoom level:
----------------------------------------

('dataBandsCount: ', 3)
('tilebands: ', 4)
(1, '/', 16912, 'tiles/16/32767/32767.png')
('\tNative Extent (querysize', 611, '): ', (0, 0, 0, 611), (611, 0, 0, 611))
('\tReadRaster Extent: ', (0, 0, 0, 611), (1024, 0, 0, 1024))
ERROR 5: Illegal values for buffer size
ERROR 5: Illegal values for buffer size
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gdal2tiles.py", line 2436, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/gdal2tiles.py", line 2433, in main
    gdal2tiles.process()
  File "/usr/bin/gdal2tiles.py", line 481, in process
    self.generate_base_tiles()
  File "/usr/bin/gdal2tiles.py", line 1309, in generate_base_tiles
    dsquery.WriteRaster(wx, wy, wxsize, wysize, data, band_list=list(range(1,self.dataBandsCount+1)))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osgeo/gdal.py", line 2000, in WriteRaster
    buf_pixel_space, buf_line_space, buf_band_space )
TypeError: not a string
```

As mentioned above, there are no errors experienced with other zoom levels, and verbose output for other levels shows a non-zero third argument to Native Extent and ReadRaster Extent.

For example for zoom level 15:

```
('dataBandsCount: ', 3)
('tilebands: ', 4)
(1, '/', 4256, 'tiles/15/16383/16383.png')
('\tNative Extent (querysize', 1223, '): ', (0, 0, 1, 1223), (1222, 0, 1, 1223))
('\tReadRaster Extent: ', (0, 0, 1, 1223), (1023, 0, 1, 1024))
```

I'm uncertain if this is a bug, or if I'm perhaps missing something with my configuration.